# How to derive output file names from sequential input files?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, filenames

I have obtained a bunch of files for a program as follows:

```
/work/xiaofenglu/science/myten.*.dump.gz
```

Now, I need to extract the string `myten.*` for the base name of sequential output files.
I use the following command to process this problem:

```
for inputfile in *.dump.gz
do
   base_name='basename ${inputfile} .dump.gz'
done
```

However, it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [parameter expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

for f in /work/xiaofenglu/science/myten.*.dump.gz; do
    base_name=${f%.dump.gz} # removes trailing .dump.gz
    base_name=${base_name##*/} # removes everything up to last / found
    printf 'Base name is: %s\n' "$base_name"
done
```

---

Your command doesn't work since you're not even calling the command `basename`. You're just defining the string `base_name` as *the verbatim string*

```
basename ${inputfile} .dump.gz
```

because of the single quotes. Maybe you saw somewhere this command:

```
base_name=`basename ${inputfile} .dump.gz`
```

and you confused the backticks ` with the single quote `'`. With backticks instead of single quotes, the command works. But it's much better to use, instead of backticks, the `$(...)` construct:

```
base_name=$(basename "$inputfile" .dump.gz)
```

which is called a [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).

But I would say it's useless to call the external process `basename` to perform something that Bash can do very well on its own.

Comment: I don't know how to put a single backtick in a post... is it even possible?

Comment: single bck-quote :  \`  yep, just escape with single backslash.

Comment: @shellter: thanks… but it's not in “code” format… it's already better than nothing `:)`.